# How to compile gcc44 in i386 mode in macports?

Tags: gcc, x86-64, macports, i386

I am trying to make command "sudo port install py25-gtk" work. The problem is that (at least) one of the dependencies (gcc44) is not compiling.

I have figured out that it always tries to compile in x86_64 mode but everything else is compiled in i386 mode. Thus, libraries do not match.

I have tried to boot my mac into 64bit mode (various methods), but failed. Also, gmp (dependency of gcc44) does not have x86_64 available.

So my only option to satisfy gcc44 dependency in 32bit mode in macports. How do I do that? How can I force compilation in i368 when "+i386" option fails to do that? +universal fails (gmp does not have x86_64)? Can I download just sources? How do I compile them?

Everything has been tried with and without -f (force) and as root. The problem occurred when I upgraded from leopard (default=i386) to snow leopard (partly x86_64, partly i386).

br,
Juha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... 20 hours later... and after asking the right question:

[How to force /usr/bin/gcc -> /usr/bin/gcc -m32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369765/how-to-force-usr-bin-gcc-usr-bin-gcc-m32)

To force compiler in 32bit mode:

hack the default compiler
   - in my case: link /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 to gcc-4.2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
    /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -m32 "$@"
```

br,

Juha