# How to force /usr/bin/gcc -> /usr/bin/gcc -m32?

Tags: macos, gcc, 64-bit, osx-snow-leopard, 32-bit

I have bad Makefile(s) of a large bundled software distribution. In some point compiler always "forgets" that I want to compile in 32 bit program. This causes that part of the programs have 64 bit libraries and others have 32 bit libraries.

How can I force -m32 option every time that I run gcc?

br,
Juha

P.S. My environment is mixed 32/64 bit (macbook5.1, snow leopard). Alternatively: How can I make my system purely 32 or 64 bits?

**edit:** Emphasis on the **bad Makefiles** that override the global variables. Thats why I chosed the hack that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a crappy hack, you could replace /usr/bin/gcc with this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/gcc-4.whatever -m32 "$@"
```

Comment: +1, I was just about to suggest this. If this doesn't work, the OP will have to hack the `Makefile`s into shape.

Comment: This is mostly running fine, but sometimes there is \-protected items. $* wraps them with "" which fails. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: @Juha: Try with `"$@"` instead of `$*`?

Comment: @nmichaels wouldnt making an alias for gcc be better than messing with files?

Comment: @chacham15: In most situations, yes. However, in this one the Makefiles' environment appeared to be messed up so I'm not sure if it would work.

Answer (score 6):

Set your `CFLAGS` environment variable to have the `-m32` flag.

`export CFLAGS="-m32"`

Comment: +1 for suggesting the right way.  I wonder if it will work with the broken Makefiles.

Comment: @Juha @Nathon - yeah, I thought about this problem more after Nathon commented. The `CFLAGS` environment variable is used by the various build tools (`configure`, `make`) but I think in Juha's case, his makefiles are unsetting flags or not using them at all at some point in the compilation.